# What does "em-pee-aitch" mean?

Tags: meaning

From the Big Lebowski movie: "Your wheel! At fifteen em-pee-aitch I roll out! I double back, grab one of 'em and beat it out of him! The uzi!".

I assume that's some kind of military slang?

Comment: I suspect you heard this rather then read it (unless it was an English subtitle)

Comment: @GWarner actually, it was a loud scene so i didn't make out anything the character said, so i read the script for the movie, the part that i quoted in the post. And i haven't ever  encountered phoneticals for letters written like that before so it didn't occur to me. I think in the dialogue i wouldve spotted it, but since it was a loud scene i couldnt make it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

em pee aitch = MPH or Miles per hour.  These are the usual units to measure speed of a vehicle in the US or UK.

15 mph is about 25 km/h

It is not military slang, it is the usual abbreviation.

Answer (score 3):

It‘s 15mph, with the letters spelled out, which stands for *miles per hour*. In metric units, 24.14 km/h.

Any American knows how fast mph is but probably not km/h because all the road signs are in mph.

Comment: It's roughly 8 km to 5 miles; Brits, being closer to the continent, often remember a few standard ones like 80 km = 50 miles, then you can get all the multiples of 10 by very simple mental arithmetic. 10 km = a shade less than 6.25 miles, so there you go. Railfans probably remember that 200 km/h = 125 mph and 300 km/h is 186 mph, as these are common running speeds for high speed trains in the UK and on the continent.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It’s just extremely rare to need to convert between miles and km in my experience, so I just Google it if I need to know. I think I’m pretty typical of Americans in this regard. The only place I routinely see km where it would be more helpful to see miles is Pokémon GO :p

Comment: When Britain went partly metric in the early 1970s, the government broadcast some informational ads on TV, including one with a jingle that went "It's easy, you see, a metre is three foot three" which I still rely on mentally.